# Convert array of strings to array of objects in JSON property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, stringify

I have the following JSON returned from an endpoint

```
{
    "response": {
        "lines": [
            "[{'line':'3007621h7s2','type':'national'},{'line':'3007663f7s9','type':'international'}]",
            "[{'line':'3007262p7f6','type':'national'},{'line':'3007262a0s1','type':'international'}]"
        ]
    }
}
```

the property `lines` is an array that should contain multiple arrays, however, as you can see, `lines` is an array of strings. How can I make each element in the lines property to be an array of objects?

Thanks

Comment: There is a typo on your code. `'line:'3007621h7s2` should be `'line':'3007621h7s2'`

Comment: The error is that your backend is json-encoding each line in a first step. You should not try to fix in the frontend the mistakes/bugs of your backend.

Comment: @Thomas that's true but let me be more clear: I don't have access to the server code so i can't modify what the response is going to be. So I'll update my question specifying that. So there is no way to do it once I get it in the front-end?

Comment: thanks @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I fixed the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to convert the strings to arrays is to `eval()` them.

```js
var obj = {
  "response": {
    "lines": [
      "[{'line':'3007621h7s2','type':'national'},{'line':'3007663f7s9','type':'international'}]",
      "[{'line':'3007262p7f6','type':'national'},{'line':'3007262a0s1','type':'international'}]"
    ]
  }
}

obj.response.lines = obj.response.lines.map(line => eval(line));

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors with your json (I dont know if that is the actual json or it was hardcoded so you might check it). The first one is

- `'line:'3007621h7s2` should be `'line':3007621h7s2`
- Values like `3007621h7s2` should be `'3007621h7s2'`

When you fix your json, then you can use `JSON.parse()` to convert the string

```js
var data = {
    "response": {
        "lines": [
            "[{'line':'3007621h7s2', 'type': 'national'},{'line':'3007663f7s9','type':'international'}]",
            "[{'line':'3007262p7f6', 'type': 'national'},{'line':'3007262a0s1','type':'international'}]"
        ]
    }
}

data.response.lines = data.response.lines.map(a=>JSON.parse(a.replace(/'/g,'"')))

console.log(
  data
)
```

Comment: Yes, they were typos. I just fixed them, so I'll try your code